# How to remove a string by index without standard library functions in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to remove a string in a vector by index but I don't have the right to use the function remove or erase in C++. Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Vector iterators are *random access* iterators, and you can add an arbitrary integer `i` to get to the element at index `i`. That information together with [a decent `std::vector` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) should be all you need.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you don't have "the right" to use erase/remove?

Comment: Do you mean without `std::erase` or without `std::vector<T>::erase`?

Comment: I have to write a function that can erase a string in a vector because I can't use the STL function erase or remove in my exercise.

Comment: Have you talked to your teacher/professor about the assignment? Can't he or she give you a hint about how to solve the problem?  Perhaps ask the teacher about the true purpose of the assignment, and what you're supposed to learn from it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) and supply it with an iterator by using [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

Assuming you have a `std::vector<std::string> vectorOfStrings` and an index `std::size_t indexToEraseAt`.

for Example:

```
auto iter = std::next(vectorOfStrings.begin(), indexToEraseAt);
vectorOfStrings.erase(iter);
```

Comment: I know but I don't have the right to use erase or remove and I want to know if there is another to do it without this two function.

Comment: This is not an answer, as the OP has mentioned ***but I don't have the right to use the function remove or erase in C++***. 
`std::vectir::erase` can't be used.

Comment: True!

The wording on the original question was a little bit confusing.